# Удалить родительский элемент по клику на вложенный элемент на jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Реализовано динамическое добавление элементов списка `<li>` с вложенными элементами `<a><i></i></a>`.
Задача удалить родительский элемент `<li>` по клику на вложенный элемент `<i>`, который в свою очередь вложен в `<a>`.

Разметка:

```
<div id="tabsSlide" class="tabs-slider">
    <ul class="tabs-slider-wrapper nav nav-tabs js_order_service_tabs">
        <li class="js_order_request_service_tab">
            <a href="#order_service" data-toggle="tab">
               <i class="icon icon-remove js_remove_service_tab"></i>Tab
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>            
</div>
```

Код удаления элемента:

```
$('#removeTab').click(function(){
 $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

[Полный код](https://jsfiddle.net/lilubanana/h9rz1tkf/1/)

Сейчас при нажатии на иконку удаления в теге `<i>` удаляются все динамически созданные элементы `<li>`. А необходимо удалить только родительский элемент `<li>` со всем содержимым.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
$('body').on('click', '.js_remove_service_tab', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('.js_order_request_service_tab').remove();
});
```

Клик навешивается через body, поскольку элементы добавляются динамически.

Comment: `closest` лучше чем `parents`, поскольку остановится, как только найдёт нужный элемент.

Comment: @Qwertiy, Спасибо. Подправил ответ.

Answer (score 2):

у Вас `removeTab` это Id, он должен быть уникален на странице

v.1

по идеи должно быть так, но событие надо вешать на каждый добавленный узел:

```
$('#tabsSlide i.icon-remove').unbind().click(function(){
  $(this).parents('li').remove();
});
```

v.2

но лучше немного поправить верстку удаляемого элемента:

```
$('#TabAdded').click(function () {
 $('#TabAdded').before('<li class="js_order_request_service_tab"><a href=""><i id="removeTab" class="icon icon-remove js_remove_service_tab" onclick="del(this)"></i>Tab</a></li>');
});
```

...

```
function del(t) {
  $(t).closest('.js_order_request_service_tab').remove();
}
```

в этом варианте ссылка на удаляемый элемент относительная

Comment: это что за `.unbind()` такой) Для чего он тут

Comment: ну наверное потому, что `click` добавляется не на один (новый) элемент, а на все найденные

Comment: это не ответ на вопрос, зачем **тут** нужен `unbind` :)

Comment: `unbind` для удаления предыдущих `event'ов`, иначе в списке из 100 позиций на первом узле будет висеть на 100 событий, на втором 99 и т.д. Хотя лучше переделать верстку, чтоб ссылка была относительной: `<i id="removeTab" class="icon icon-remove js_remove_service_tab" onclick="del(this)"></i>` `function del(t){$(t).closest('.js_order_request_service_tab').remove();}`

Comment: добавь в свой ответ твое предложение, подскажи задающему как сделать правильней.

Comment: Что такое v.1? И вообще, жесть какая-то.

Comment: вариант1, вариант2, 
 ЖЭСТЬ - это когда скрипт будет по 100500 раз запускать одну и ту же обработку на странице, как в соседнем ответе, т.к. он ничего не найдет, то вроде как и работает без ошибок, но потом будем удивляться чего такая страница `тяжелая`

Comment: сделала v.2 но все равно удаляет все созданные табы https://jsfiddle.net/lilubanana/h9rz1tkf/2/

Comment: jsfiddle не очень дружит с Вашим кодом, внес коррективы, так работает: http://jsfiddle.net/h9rz1tkf/4